# copying a string in C++ "Error reading characters of string."

Tags: c++, string, copy

I am implementing a stack and I would like to push and pop string data. can I not just set

string name = originalString   ???

here is what I have for push:

```
void push(StackNode** top_ref, int nAttack, int nDefense, string nName, string nType) {
    StackNode* stackNode = (StackNode*)malloc(sizeof(StackNode));
    stackNode->attack = nAttack;
    stackNode->defense = nDefense;

    stackNode->name = nName; //not working
    stackNode->type = nType; //not working

    stackNode->next = NULL;
    stackNode->next = *top_ref;
    *top_ref = stackNode;
}
```

where stackNode->name

and stackNode->type is already defind as a string

I keep getting: "Error reading characters of string."

Comment: Is this for an academic class where you're required to use `malloc`? If not, can I introduce you to `new[]`? And then after you've gotten accustomed to that, can I introduce you to `std::stack`? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack

Comment: Can you show the `StackNode` class please?

Comment: Yepp new made it work, although I am not quite sure why it is so different to malloc. Thanks for the help! I replaced malloc with this for future people
StackNode* stackNode = new StackNode;

Comment: `malloc` is dumb and only gives you that amount of memory. The constructor isn't called. With `new`, the constructor is called. That's the difference.

Comment: But to be clear - this is for an academic exercise where you're required to do your own memory management? Because the C++ best practice is to use STL containers when they're appropriate. Here, you'd use `std::stack`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is `malloc` doesn't play well with objects. See [Does malloc create a new instance of the class or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29151814/does-malloc-create-a-new-instance-of-the-class-or-not)

`malloc` allocates enough space to hold a `StackNode`, but doesn't call the constructor on it. Nor does it create the underlying member objects, your `string`s included. To do so, you need to do like described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995099/malloc-and-constructors) answer:

```
A* a = (A*)malloc(sizeof(A));
new (a) A();

a->~A();
free(a);
```

But at this point, you really should just be using `new` anyway. There's very little reason to use `new` in C++ (there's a time and a place, but minimize it). There's even fewer times when it's right to call `malloc`.

Do

```
StackNode* stackNode = new StackNode;
```

which will call the constructor appropriately. Remember to call `delete` on the memory when you're done with it!

Comment: thanks John, it was definitely "new" that was needed thanks for the explanation as well!